# Is the CELL-ID stored in HLR database , how to get location of a Cell-Id

Tags: mobile, gsm, cellid

Is it easy to get the current LIST of mobile phone users under a particular tower(cell-id) from the Home Location Register, does the network operators or service providers have mapping of location information to a particular cell like latitude ,longitude.

Answer (score 2):

To get actual cell id of a mobile phone form HLR/VLR - you should use SS7 signaling commands: `sendRoutingInfoForSM` and `provideSubscriberInfo`

To ged cell id latitude/longitude - you can use services like [opencellid.org](http://opencellid.org/) or [locationapi.org](http://locationapi.org/)

Answer (score 1):

someonespecial

You will not get this information from the HLR.

Obviously operators know where their own cells are but it's often considered business intelligence and not public information.

Comment: ..I agree with you, what i wanted to ask is if                      1).When ever a MSC receives an sms from a mobile can that MSC query the HLR to get the cell-id of that mobile which had sent the sms??                                              2).Can the MSC use FORWARD_MESSAGE option by itself...

Answer (score 0):

There are some commercial and non-commercial list of cell towers and their GPS locations but those information may not be updated real time and may misguide you because of continuous operational tasks carried by MNOs such as moving cell stations to another locations, installing or decommissioning them.

There are several ways to get current cell id of mobile number but all require integration with MNO’s equipment using with either SS7 protocol suite or other available proprietary interfaces.

- Sending AnyTimeInterrogation MAP operation to HLR and processing its response
- Getting Location Update dumps by means of core network specific interface or port mirroring on L3 switches of HLR for all Sigtran links between HLR and MSSs.
- Using existing SMLC platform of MNO

But it would not be enough to build up-to-date geolocation database. In any case you would need to get CELL ID/LAC/GPS location list regularly as exportable dump from MNO you are willing to work.